# Django on Apache web server 'dict' object has no attribute 'render_context'

Tags: python, html, django, apache, mod-python

I'm having a bit of a problem, I uploaded my Django project to a webserver running apache, mod_python, and django. On the computer I developed on the following works fine

```
nameBox = getNamesBox().render(locals())
```

-

```
def getNamesBox():
    users = User.objects.filter()

    templateString = '<select name="name box">'
    for user in users:
        templateString += '<option value="' + user.name + '"> ' + user.name + '</option>'

    templateString += '</select>'

    template = Template(templateString)

    return template
```

But on the web server, when running from apache or manage.py runserver, it says

```
AttributeError at /order_site/order/
'dict' object has no attribute 'render_context'
```

The code on both machines is identical so I feel like maybe its some other issue? It can't render my form and I don't know why.

Comment: You seem to have missed the whole point of templates, there. Why create the text manually using concatentation and then "rendering" something that contains no template syntax, rather than actually using a template file with proper template logic that can do all that for you?

Comment: Or, better yet, use form classes.

Comment: @Rafe well, yes, indeed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `render()` method on a `Template` takes a `Context` object as its argument, not a dict. You'll have to construct a `Context` object from the dict, e.g.

```
namedbox = getNamesBox().render(Context(locals()))
```

Comment: Can be imported with `from django.template import Context`

Comment: in newer versions `render()` takes a dict as context which does not have this method

Comment: @patroqueeet I have been said so too. But I have seen the `Template,render()` implementation of Django 1.11. There it tries to access render_context attribute of the passed dict object. In my  case it raised an error when I passed a dict object. It says, "`dict object has no attribute 'render_context'` . "