# Converting HTML to PDF using Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert my HTML into PDF but I am getting the following error:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'render_context'.

The code is below:

## utils.py

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

## views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
from django.template.loader import get_template
from admin.views.utils import render_to_pdf  # created in step 4


def get_pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    template = get_template('certificate_appreciation_pdf.html')
    context = {
        'today': datetime.date.today(),
        'amount': 39.99,
        'customer_name': 'Cooper Mann',
        'order_id': 1233434,
    }
    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('certificate_appreciation_pdf.html', context)
```

## certificate_appreciation_pdf.html

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
     <head>
         <title>Title</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class='wrapper'>
             <div class='header'>
                 <p class='title'>Invoice # </p>
             </div>
         <div>
         <div class='details'>
             Bill to: {{ order_id }}<br/>
             Amount: {{ amount }} <br/>
             Date: {{ today }}
             <hr class='hrItem' />
         </div>
     </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

I don't know where I am making an error.
Error I got when rendering to that page

```
AttributeError at /pdf/
'dict' object has no attribute 'render_context'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8001/pdf/
Django Version: 1.5.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'dict' object has no attribute 'render_context'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in render, line 138
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/linux/Desktop/project_directory/nasscom-final/django-pursuite/pursuite/../apps',
 './apps',
 '/home/linux/Desktop/project_directory/nasscom-final/django-pursuite',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pursuite-1.7.18-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.45.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_pagination-1.0.7-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Jinja2-2.9.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Sphinx-1.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Wed, 21 Jun 2017 14:34:08 +0530
```

Comment: Could you paste all logs please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django on Apache web server 'dict' object has no attribute 'render\_context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333367/django-on-apache-web-server-dict-object-has-no-attribute-render-context)

Comment: http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/ is best option to convert HTML to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a **very** old (and unsupported) version of Django. In that version, you need to pass a Context instance to `template.render`, not a dict.

```
from django.template import Context
...
context = Context({...})
html = template.render(context)
```

But, you **must** upgrade. There is no reason to be using Django 1.5 at this point.

Comment: Thanks it's working f9 now....if I upgrade to django 1.10 or 1.9 do I need to change the packages installed or code because it's a big project  running on  django 1.5.